# Async page en aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynctask, aspx

Estoy desarrollando una página web con .NET

Tengo un método para enviar correos electrónicos el cual quiero realizarlo de manera asincrona. Hasta aquí todo se ha realizado correctamente, pero en el diseño de las vistas .aspx tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo una estructura MasterPage -> Page donde la Page se puede declarar como asyncrona pero en cambio la Master no lo es. Esto lo declaro de la siguiente manera.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Administration/Administration.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GestionUsuarios.aspx.cs" Inherits="Administration.GestionUsuarios" Async="true"%>
```

En cambio en Administration.Master no es posible declararla como asincrona. Por lo que el método sigue ejecutandose como sincrono.

No encuentro una solución a esto.

Gracias.

Comment: por que no creas un web service o un webmethod para poder simplemente invocarlos sin esperar respuesta ? 

No creo que sea recomendable hacer operaciones asincronas desde el back end en ASP.Net, dado que el front end jamas recibirá la respuesta

Comment: la otra opcion es no utilizar un master page. las masterpages no pueden ser asincronas, suena a dolor de cabeza pero posiblmente tendras que hacer que esa pagina deje de heredar del master page... ooo bien invocar tu webmethod desde el front end si es posible.

Comment: La opción más factible ahora mismo es crear está página en concreto a piñon sin master page... menuda gracia, pero es lo que hay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por qué no simplemente en el evento en el cual pretendes enviar el correo llama un método asincrono, en este define un thread, lo configuras y posteriormente lo lanzas, mira un ejemplo:

```
    private void MiMetodoSincrono(string parametroX)
    {
                    Thread currentThread = new Thread(() => MiMetodoAsincrono(parametros));
                    currentThread.Start();/*aqui disparas el hilo para que envie el correo*/
                    //codigo  /*este codigo continua en el hilo actual y no va a esperar a que termine el envio del correo*/
    }

    public async void MiMetodoAsincrono(parametros) //método asincrono
    {
                    //codigo de enviar correo
    }
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias! @MichaelOspina de momento voy a intentar realizarlo mediante hilos, pero por otro lado, hay que parar los hilos? o mueren cuando finalizan?

Comment: Termina el proceso y muere